# Direct Admin Cronjob Not creating files

Tags: php, createfile

I am currently having an issue with creating files on my server due a cronjob.
I use Direct Admin on a Linux server.
This is my cronjob line:

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/USER/domains/MYDOMAIN.COM/public_html/system/generate.php
```

The script basicly does this:

1. Create a database record in `table_1`
2. Update a row in the database in `table_2`
3. Create a `.zip` file on the server.

When I run the script by myself it does all that.
But once the cronjob runs the script it does everything except Step 3 (Create a `.zip` file on the server).

I'm running out of ideas, it has to be something with the cronjob because when I run the script myself it works perfect! Did I wrote the cronjob wrong? Do I need to add something to be able to write files on the server (something with cronjob permissions??).

Comment: Either an issue with permissions (_which_ cronjob?) or with the current working directory the script is started in.

Comment: @WiktorMociun What does `wget` have to do with this?

Comment: Ohh sorry, my bad, didn't read your post with enough attention. Sorry for that. :)

Comment: True, this seems to be permission issue, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475694/how-to-specify-in-crontab-by-what-user-to-run-script, make sure you create the crontab as your current running user.

Comment: Crontab is the cronjobline? Wich would make mine: crontab -u www-data -e /usr/local/bin/php /home/USER/domains/MYDOMAIN.COM/public_html/system/generate.php 
Am I right? :)