# run selenium with crontab (python)

Tags: python, ubuntu, selenium, cron

I have a python script that calls chrome via selenium with the next line.

```
 ff = webdriver.Chrome('/home/user01/webScraping/CollectAndGo/chromedriver')
```

The python script is called from a shell script.

```
python /home/user01/webScraping/CollectAndGo/cgcom.py > /home/user01/webScraping/CollectAndGo/cgcom.log 2>&1
```

When I run the script from the terminal or just executing the .sh file it works perfectly but when I schedule a crontab job it fail with the next error.

```
   raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: u'unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248304,platform=Linux 3.5.0-36-generic x86_64)'
```

The error is related to the first line of code of this question. Does anybody know why this could be happening?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The most evident problem with trying to launch a browser from `cron` is that even if you have X running on your machine, the `DISPLAY` environment variable is not set for processes running from your `crontab` so launching a browser from there will fail.

Solutions range from the trivial to the super sophisticated. A trivial solution would be to accept that your script won't run if there is no X running and manually set `DISPLAY` to `:0`, which is the default display number for the default X server that Ubuntu starts.

For instance, if I put this command in the `command` column of a `crontab` line, Chrome starts without issue:

```
DISPLAY=:0 google-chrome
```

The complete line in the a user-specific crontab file would be something like:

```
0 * * * *  DISPLAY=:0 google-chrome
```

If you want to run a python script that starts chrome through selenium, the line would instead look like:

```
0 * * * *  DISPLAY=:0 python my_script.py
```

The command string is just sent as-is to the shell so in the last example the string `DISPLAY=:0 python my_script.py` would be just passed to the shell. It is common shell syntax to interpret a variable assignment given immediately at the start of the command as setting an environment variable. (It is certainly the case for `dash` and `bash`, one of which is likely to be the default shell in most installations.) So the command that the shell interprets sets the environment variable `DISPLAY` to the value `:0` and then runs `python my_script.py`. Since `python` inherits its environment from the shell that started it, the variable `DISPLAY` is `:0` for it too.

Setting `DISPLAY=:0` like I show above sets the variable *only* for the command that follows. It is also possible to set `DISPLAY` to `:0` for all commands executed by the crontab. For instance in the following user-specific crontab:

```
DISPLAY=:0

30 * * * *  google-chrome
0  * * * *  python my_script.py
```

the line `DISPLAY=:0` sets the environment variable `DISPLAY` both for the execution of `google-chrome` and `python my_script.py`

Comment: yeha that did the trick! thanks! (how do you guys know these things?!)

Comment: Would you use this on the same line as your script or a different one?
 ie, 1 = `0 * * * * python3 my_script.py DISPLAY=:0 google-chrome` or 2 =`DISPLAY=:0 google-chrome  [\n]                                                                                
 0 * * * * python3 my_script.py`?

Comment: @JessicaChambers I've edited my answer to explain. Neither of your choices are quite correct.

Comment: Of course, there will not be a running X session on `:0` if you are not logged in to your desktop. A robust solution would start up a separate `Xvfb` server from your `cron` job, and then run Chrome within a new headless session. This creates a number of additional complications, so there is definitely a tradeoff between robustness and simplicity.

Answer (score 4):

Use [pyvirtualdisplay and Xvfb](https://github.com/ponty/pyvirtualdisplay/tree/2.1) to manage your window session for you (originally from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45550850/11671779))

**Background:**

In my case, the accepted answer is not working.

**Solution:**

1. Install PyVirtualDisplay and Xvfb

```sh
pip3 install pyvirtualdisplay
sudo apt-get install xvfb
```

2. Assign window handler in your `.py` script

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
import time

# Display creates a virtual frame buffer and manages it for you
with Display(visible=False, size=(1200, 1500)):
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get("https://website-target.com")

    time.sleep(1)

    print(driver.current_url) # check connection

    time.sleep(1)

    print(driver.current_url)

    driver.close()
```

Comment: Took me 2 days to find solution. Only your answer worked. Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

on MacOS Catalina only this command worked for me

```sh
* * * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin && /usr/bin/python3 ~/Documents/Scripts/my_script.py
```

Answer (score 0):

selenium web drivers needs X session for running script. Cron scripts normally runs with out X session. Add X session in your cron script. Like as follows:
* 11 * * * export DISPLAY=:0; your script.py

Answer (score -1):

Crontab is likely running as a user that doesn't have permission to access the chromedriver directory/file.

Take a look at the [answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475694/how-to-specify-in-crontab-by-what-user-to-run-script) on how to run crontab as a specific user.

Comment: nope, the user stuff is right and he has the permissions to execute chromedriver.