# Selenium script working from console, not working in CRON - Geckodriver error

Tags: python, linux, selenium, cron

I have Selenium script running from SH file.
It is working perfectly fine when I run sh file from console,
but the same file ran from Cron job fails.

SH file:

```
#!/bin/sh

export DISPLAY=:10
cd /home/user
python3 selenium.py > /home/user/selenium.log 2>&1
```

Error which I am getting is well known:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py",
>   line 74, in start
>       stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 947, in **init**
>       restore_signals, start_new_session)   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1551, in _execute_child
>       raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg) FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'geckodriver'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "so_login.py", line 12, in
>   setUp
>       self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py",
>   line 142, in **init**
>       self.service.start()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py",
>   line 81, in start
>       os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message) selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver'
>   executable needs to be in PATH.

I have this error in console too, but I solved it by installing geckodriver and moving it to /usr/local/bin and it is working fine from console, but why it is not working from CRON ?

Comment: If you need an X-Windows/GUI session then it won't work with crontab as crontab doesn't know which X-Windows session to associate itself with.

Comment: how to make it work? I use it headless like described here https://medium.com/@griggheo/running-selenium-webdriver-tests-using-firefox-headless-mode-on-ubuntu-d32500bb6af2

Comment: Cron assumes not display and so no frame buffers. I therefore can't see it working with Cron. Have you looked into scheduling with Jenkins instead?

Comment: @RamanSailopal sure it can work.  Use XVFB as a virtual framebuffer for X

Answer (score 3):

Consider using [pyvirtualdisplay](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyVirtualDisplay) to manage your window session for you

Install it with pip

```
$ pip install pyvirtualdisplay
```

Then add something like the following to your code:

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display


def main():
    # Display creates a virtual frame buffer and manages it for you
    with Display(visible=False, size=(1200, 1500)):
        # Run the test of your code here

    # When your code is finished and exits the with block, the with
    # context manager cleans up the virtual display for you


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```