# Why my scheduled job is not working?

Tags: linux, centos, cron, vertica

I define a job with **crontab** like this

```
0 2 * * * dbadmin . /home/dbadmin/back.sh
```

it is not **root** I want to run this **.sh** file with **dbadmin** user.

but when I checked it is not working.

in the log it gives this:

```
Feb 22 21:16:01 localhost crond[14634]: (*system*) BAD FILE MODE (/etc/crontab)
Feb 22 21:16:01 localhost crond[14634]: (dbadmin) RELOAD (cron/dbadmin)
Feb 22 21:16:01 localhost crond[28451]: (dbadmin) CMD (dbadmin . /home/dbadmin/back.sh)
```

How can I fix this? thanks in advance

Comment: redirect the standard output and standard error to log to check error if any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a crontab entry as dbadmin without the username in it:

```
0 2 * * * /home/dbadmin/movefolder.sh > /home/dbadmin/cron.out 2>@1
```

Each day the logfile /home/dbadmin/cron.out should be replaced by a new one.
When you are confident about the cron+movefolder, replace the outputfile with `/dev/null`.
When above fails, check calling the script as dbadmin:

```
sh /home/dbadmin/movefolder.sh
```

When this one works and cron fails, it might be the environment. Try saomething like

```
0 2 * * * . /home/dbadmin/.profile; /home/dbadmin/movefolder.sh > /home/dbadmin/cron.out 2>@1
```

Comment: hi , thanks for answer  it gives this log, but it does not do what I expect from it :    Feb 22 21:37:01 localhost crond[14634]: (dbadmin) RELOAD (cron/dbadmin)
Feb 22 21:37:01 localhost crond[31546]: (dbadmin) CMD (sh /home/dbadmin/back.sh)

Comment: You started it from root's cron again. Try small steps, first from commandline and then from local cron. Or replace your script `date` and redirect output again.

Answer (score 1):

Using the crontab program, you normally have access only to the 5 scheduling fields (minute, hour, day of month, month and day of week).  However, with Vixie cron (usually on Linux) by editing the *system* crontab file (/etc/crontab, as well as files in /etc/cron.d) you can use the 6th field for the username.  For example, see [How to specify in crontab by what user to run script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475694/how-to-specify-in-crontab-by-what-user-to-run-script)

If you use crontab to enter this line

```
0 2 * * * dbadmin . /home/dbadmin/back.sh
          ^^^^^^^
```

the "dbadmin" username is treated as the command to execute.  You can (as noted in [crontab](http://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab)'s manual page) use that line in /etc/crontab.  I pointed out that this is *Vixie* (also known as [ISC](http://isc.org/)) crontab.  Legacy systems such as [Solaris](http://www.manpages.info/sunos/crontab.1.html) have a less capable crontab which would not allow specifying the user to run under.

According to [cron](http://linux.die.net/man/8/cron)'s manual page, it will send output via email.  Perhaps there was no email because the command "dbadmin" failed.

Comment: thanks for answer , but it does not work, where is the log ? I can not find the logs

Comment: Usually cron is setup to send via email whatever was written to the standard error.  Looking at the description of Vixie cron (manpage), it does not make that distinction -- but email is where I would look.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use sh command for executing sh file.like following

```
0 2 * * * dbadmin sh /home/dbadmin/movefolder.sh
```

Hope it works. 
Thank you.

Comment: it is not working :( how can I understand why it is not working , I can t see log