# Laravel not running Cronjob on Ubuntu NGINX

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, nginx, cron

I have setup the follow Laravel Cronjob command:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('DataDownloader:downloaddata')->dailyAt('19:34');
}
```

This saves some data from an API into a mySQL database. The command is listed under `php artisan` and I am able to run it using `php artisan DataDownloader:downloaddata`.

I have added the Cron entry to my `crontab` as per Laravel documentation:

`* * * * * php /var/www/html/myprojectname/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

When I run `php artisan schedule:run` it tells me 'No scheduled commands are ready to run'. I don't really know if this suggests if my Cronjob does not work at all or it is just broken.

Am I missing something or did I do something wrong that prevents the Cron from running?

My server is running Ubuntu with NGINX.

Comment: What user did "add the cron entry"  to crontab? You may want to see https://stackoverflow.com/a/8476992/1564365

Comment: @Kyslik I first tried a user that I added using `usermod -aG` and then the root account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`schedule:run` command fires other commands that are ready to run at the time of its execution. So it means that in that exact time you ran it, no command was to be started.

However, you have defined cron that runs `schedule:run` every minute, thus when 19:34 comes, your command will be executed.

Comment: I guess that be logical - but is there any way to know that the commands will be run or do I just have to wait for them to happen?

Comment: Sadly, I'm not aware of any such built-in possibility so far besides waiting.

Comment: I will see if it Cron works and report back to you. Thanks!