# Execute PHP in cron job on centos

Tags: php, cron, centos

I needed help on my cronjob experiment, im unable to accomplish what i wanted. below are the things I did.

1. Create a php file inside `/var/www/html/bob/test/index.php`
2. Set permission rights of the directory and file to executable (0777)
3. Specify a cronjob

My **index.php**

```
<?php 
$myfile = fopen("testfile.txt", "w");  
?>
```

My various tested parameters for **crontab -e** which didn't work

```
*/1 * * * * root /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/bob/test/index.php
*/1 * * * * root /var/www/html/bob/test/index.php
*/1 * * * * root php -q /var/www/html/bob/test/index.php
*/1 * * * * root /var/www/html/bob/test/index.php
```

looking at some of my **/var/log/cron** I dont see any error indication.

```
Sep 6 15:55:01 localhost CROND[4866]: (root) CMD (root /var/www/html/bob/test/index.php)
Sep 6 15:56:01 localhost CROND[4872]: (root) CMD (root /var/www/html/bob/test/index.php)
Sep 6 15:57:01 localhost CROND[4878]: (root) CMD (root /var/www/html/bob/test/index.php)
```

Lastly, when i run my php via `#php /var/www/html/bob/test/index.php` the code executes fine and creates that textfile.

Comment: did you check  the php error log?

Comment: try to use the absolute path for the file testfile.txt like :

 $myfile = fopen("/home/xxxx/testfile.txt", "w");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove `root` from your cronjob. The log is showing it's trying to execute a program called root with `/var/www/html/bob/test/index.php` as a parameter.

Instead, use the following as your cronjob:

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/bob/test/index.php
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8475757/1561469) states that if you want to set the user for a cronjob to be run, you have to edit `/etc/crontab` directly, not by using `crontab -e`.

Comment: Thanks for your time, removing only the `root` didnt seem to fix it, but combined with @abderrahime comment, to include absolute path and removing `root` did work.

Comment: No problem, glad you got it sorted :)

Answer (score 0):

```
1 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/bob/test/index.php
```

if this not working, so you have a probleme of permission , try to use chown and chmod for giving the right permission

and for $myfile = fopen("testfile.txt", "w");  try to use the absolute path for the file testfile.txt like :

```
 $myfile = fopen("/home/xxxx/testfile.txt", "w");
```

Comment: it must be a comment, not an answer