# CakePHP 3 Cache File Permissions

Tags: cakephp, amazon-ec2, cron, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.4

I have a CakePHP 3 app with shells that I run from crontab.

When I run the shells through crontab, it creates cache files owned by the user running the crontab, which is not the user that runs apache...

Sometimes when I run the crontab the cached models are owned by apache and the shell fails, sometimes when I visit a page the models are owned by ec2-user and the page fails...

I posted a question on github, https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/11265#issuecomment-333951638

I was told to modify the chmod option for the cache config, I tried the following but it didn't work...

```
/**
 * Configure the cache adapters.
 */
'Cache' => [
    'default' => [
        'className' => 'File',
        'path' => CACHE,
        'url' => env('CACHE_DEFAULT_URL', null),
        'chmod' => 777
    ],
```

Any ideas on how I can make the default file permissions 777 on the cake cache files?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to [**create the crontab for / run the crontab as the required user**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475694/how-to-specify-in-crontab-by-what-user-to-run-script)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest having the chron run as the correct user OR having the chron task change owner and keep permissions as set but if you really want to have it all as it is and just change the permissions then you can use the `mask` option which I assume is what they meant.

[Cache Config Options](https://api.cakephp.org/3.5/class-Cake.Cache.Engine.FileEngine.html#$_defaultConfig)

Set using the following:

```
'Cache' => [
    'default' => [
        'mask' => 0777,
        // other config options
    ],
]
```

Comment: @mart In your cron you can add something to change the ownership of the files as well. This might be an easier solution to get exactly what you want.

Comment: resolved it with `'mask' => '0666',` which works fine. Thanks.

Comment: @mart No it doesn't! WARNING: Do not quote this value! Should be `'mask' => 0666`

Answer (score 1):

@KaffineAddict is correct but make sure you do not wrap the value of mask in quotes as this can cause the values to not give correct permissions.

```
'Cache' => [
    'default' => [
        'mask' => 0777,
        // other config options
    ],
]
```

Comment: I updated the accepted answer to include you contribution, thanks!