# Cronjob - Unable to find Mozilla geckodriver

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, cron, rbenv, geckodriver

I have geckodriver installed in the `usr/local/bin` directory and exported to the $PATH variable.

`export PATH=$PATH:~/usr/local/bin/geckodriver`

You can see `usr/local/bin` is in my $PATH

`root/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:/root/.rbenv/shims:/root/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin`

However, I run the ruby script by cronjob I get the following error message: **Unable to find Mozilla geckodriver.**

My Cronjob

`*/20 * * * * ~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec ruby /home/path/to/the/ruby/script/report_export.rb`

I start the ruby script so it all works. Can someone help me that it also works by cronjob

Comment: I suggest you to use legacy firefox driver which is far better than geckodriver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be that your export is located in place which is not called by cron daemon.

To investigate that replace your cronjob with `echo $PATH >> /tmp/crontab.log` and then check '/tmp/crontab.log' for PATH and check if `/usr/local/bin` is there.

Another reason could be that cron daemon is running as different user and thus has no access to geckodriver. Check `ls -la /usr/local/bin | grep gecko`. If that's the case, please checkout [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475694/how-to-specify-in-crontab-by-what-user-to-run-script)