# How to run git pull from subprocess

Tags: python, git

I am trying to run a subprocess command to do a `git pull`.

The cwd of the Git repository is `/home/ubuntu/Ingest`.

The `id_rsa` that I'm using with Github is located at `/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa`.

How would I run a subprocess call to do the following?

```
import shlex, subprocess
subprocess.call(shlex.split('git pull origin master'), cwd='/home/ubuntu/Ingest')
```

The log looks like:

```
movies_ec2.py:43@__init__ [INFO] Version not up to date...Doing a git pull and exiting...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

The script is running from `cron` and is not picking up on the `id_rsa`. (Note: I am not looking to use GitPython). What do I need to change in my cron job or script so that this will work? My cron job is currently:

```
# sudo crontab -e
*/1 * * * * STAGE=production /home/ubuntu/Ingest/ingest/movies_ec2.py > /home/ubuntu/test.log 2>&1
```

Comment: try to check current user when running as cron: cron is run by a different user, maybe not `ubuntu`. so permissions issue...

Comment: also don't use shlex.split, just pass the arguments as a list, it's simpler.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre it seems to be running as the `root` user fron `sudo crontab  -e`. What should I change this to?

Comment: not sure, not a linux expert, but you can create a crontab running with a specific user, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475694/how-to-specify-in-crontab-by-what-user-to-run-script

Comment: Make sure that `HOME=/home/ubuntu` in the context of your cron job. (Towards this end, make sure you're putting this in the ubuntu user's crontab, not root's).

Comment: BTW, it's better form to hardcode the list -- `['git', 'pull', 'origin', 'master']`, without the `shlex.split()` involvement. You'll be glad you went that route when you need to be able to substitute in values that can contain spaces without needing to worry about shell-equivalent escaping first.

Answer (score 0):

The following answer addresses this question quite well: [How to specify in crontab by what user to run script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475694/how-to-specify-in-crontab-by-what-user-to-run-script). However, in short, this can be accomplished by modifying the user in the crontab to be "ubuntu", which is the current user that is used to create all the files, etc.

```
$ sudo vim /etc/crontab
*/1 * * * *     ubuntu   /home/ubuntu/Ingest/ingest/movies_ec2.py > /home/ubuntu/test.log 2>&1
```

Comment: Also, you could've used the crontab from the ubuntu user itself. (`crontab -e` when logged in as ubuntu) With `sudo crontab -e` you were writing to root's crontab.