# cron job does not read & write to log file when executed the cron

Tags: php

I am new to using cron jobs, but I have studied the basics. I am able to call php using cron tab. 
When run manually, the code is executed. But when it is run from the cron job php can't read the log file.

```
$log = 'text.log';  
$saved = 10; 
$deleted_line = count(file($log))-$saved; 
$chk_size = filesize($log)/1024;
if($chk_size >= 2048) {
 $total_lines = file($log);  
    $final_lines = array_slice($total_lines, $deleted_line);
    $file = fopen('amrut-all-projects.log', 'w');
    $result = fwrite($file, implode('', $final_lines));
    fclose($file); 
    }  else { 
       echo 'Your File size less then 5kb.'; 
}
```

Comment: Make sure you know under whose privileges the process is being executed, and in which directory. It is likely not what you expected.

Comment: Add your cron command here, that would help.

Comment: Check the owner and permission of both php script and log file.

Comment: /usr/local/bin/php /home/moud/public_html/amrut/schedular/test-amrut-all-projects.php  Hi This

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are specifying the wrong path.

Try this

```
/path/to/php -f /path/to/script.php >> /path/to/logfile.log
```

Comment: wow Greate.... AWSOME Abhishek Mishra thanku  for your supporting thaks a lot sir

Answer (score 0):

First of all please hit the CRON file manually using the browser. If the output came perfectly then don't worry about your code. Try to check the CRON settings.

Comment: Hi Fistley I Hit the manually cron file using the browser I got output . But when i am using cron file to run that time it cn't read log file . Please check this is my cron command . 

$file_ log = '/usr/local/bin/php /home/moud/public_html/amrut/schedular/test-amrut-all-projects.php ';

Comment: Can you please tell me what should i check in CRON settings.

Answer (score 0):

@Amadan gave you a right hint. Below you have steps what to do:

```
ls -ld folder_u_try_to_save_to/
```

This will show you which user and group has access to your destination folder. If it's your_user then try to run cron with:

```
su -l your_user -c 'crontab -e'
```

If it works correctly then check out this answer => [How to specify in crontab by what user to run script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475694/how-to-specify-in-crontab-by-what-user-to-run-script)
on how to create cron tab for specific user and add this user to a group that has access to the folder you are trying to save data to.

Comment: Hi Fistley I Hit the manually cron file using the browser I got output . But when i am using cron file to run that time it cn't read log file . Please check this is my cron command . 

$file_ log = '/usr/local/bin/php /home/moud/public_html/amrut/schedular/test-amrut-all-projects.php ';

Comment: If it's working via browser then you should run it as www-data user.
I see you are calling it directly, try this:  
sudo -u www-data /usr/local/bin/php /home/moud/public_html/amrut/schedular/test-amrut-all-projects.php

Obviously you need to have sudo access in sudoers.

Comment: Hi can i use this command 

($file_log = -u www-data /usr/local/bin/php /home/moud/public_html/amrut/schedular/amrut-all-projects.log)

if i am using this command then i am not access the file data please help us.

 $file_log = 'www-data/usr/local/bin/php/home/moud/public_html/amrut/schedular/amrut-all-projects.log';
 
    $res =  file($file_log);
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($res);die;

Comment: response please.

Comment: what is the output of 'ls -al amrut-all-projects.log' ?

Comment: Basically i want to save 200 line of code in log file (amrut-all-projects.log'). If Hit the manually cron file using the browser I got output  [ Note ] If i am using cron that time cron job is not read the file path  how can i mention log file path please tell me . My code is this pls see

Comment: $log = 'amrut-all-projects.log';  
$saved = 200; 
$deleted_line = count(file($log))-$saved; 
$chk_size = filesize($log)/1024;
if($chk_size >= 2048) {
 $total_lines = file($log);  
    $final_lines = array_slice($total_lines, $deleted_line);
    $file = fopen('amrut-all-projects.log', 'w');
    $result = fwrite($file, implode('', $final_lines));
    fclose($file); 
    }  else { 
       echo 'Your File size less then 5mb.'; 
}