# Execute PHP script in cron job

Tags: php, linux, apache, cron, centos

In our centos6 server. I would like to execute a php script in cron job as apache user but unfortunately it does not work.

Here is the edition of crontab (crontab -uapache -e)

```
24 17 * * * php /opt/test.php
```

and here is the source code of "test.php" file which works fine with "apache" user as owner.

```
<?php exec( 'touch /opt/test/test.txt');?>
```

I try to replace php with full path of php (/usr/local/php/bin/php) but also it doesn't work.

Comment: Surely just having "php" would be enough? In my experience using CentOS, it can be a BIG nightmare getting PHP configured correctly with all the security and whatnot that it entails.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

#### [Automated Tasks: Cron](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/ch-autotasks.html)

Cron is a time-based scheduling service in Linux / Unix-like computer operating systems. Cron job are used to schedule commands to be executed periodically.
You can setup commands or scripts, which will repeatedly run at a set time. Cron is one of the most useful tool in Linux or UNIX like operating systems. The cron service (daemon) runs in the background and constantly checks the */etc/crontab* file, */etc/cron.*/* directories. It also checks the */var/spool/cron/* directory.

#### Configuring Cron Tasks

In the following example, the *crontab command* shown below will activate the cron tasks automatically every ten minutes:

```
*/10 * * * * /usr/bin/php /opt/test.php
```

In the above sample, the */10 * * * * represents when the task should happen. The first figure represents *minutes* – in this case, on every "ten" minute. The other figures represent, respectively, *hour*, *day*, *month* and *day of the week*.

*`*` is a wildcard, meaning "every time"*.

Start with finding out your *PHP* binary by typing in command line:

```
whereis php
```

The output should be something like:

> php: /usr/bin/php /etc/php.ini /etc/php.d /usr/lib64/php /usr/include/php /usr/share/php /usr/share/man/man1/php.1.gz

Specify correctly the full path in your command.

#### Type the following command to enter cronjob:

```
crontab -e
```

To see what you got in *crontab*.

#### EDIT 1:

To exit from vim editor without saving just click:

```
Shift+:
```

And then type `q!`

Comment: Thanks for your response, I did that but i would like to execute the script in apache crontab (crontab -uapache -e) which doesn't work yet. in fact the script work fine in crontab root (when I add it in crontab -e)

Comment: @Khalilos It should be `crontab -u apache -e`, is that what you meant?

Comment: yes it is, but it does not work when i add the script in 'crontab -u apache -e'

Comment: Should it be `/usr/bin/php -f /opt/test.php`, rather than `/usr/bin/php /opt/test.php`?

Comment: @user2768 `Both ways (whether using the -f switch or not) execute the file my_script.php. Note that there is no restriction on which files can be executed; in particular, the filename is not required have a .php extension.`
http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.usage.php

Comment: If you want many PHP files running as a cron job, you can put all of them into a .sh file, such as this myExample.sh:
#!bin/bash
/usb/bin/php  /var/www/html/yourdomain/file1.php
/usb/bin/php  /var/www/html/yourdomain/file2.php
/usb/bin/php  /var/www/html/yourdomain/file3.php
...

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem... I had to run it as a user.

```
00 * * * * root /usr/bin/php /var/virtual/hostname.nz/public_html/cronjob.php
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to run the cron job as a user with permissions to execute the PHP script. Try executing the cron job as root, using the command `runuser` (`man runuser`). Or create a system crontable and run the PHP script as an authorized user, as @Philip described.

I provide a detailed answer how to use cron in this stackoverflow post.

[How to write a cron that will run a script every day at midnight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984134/cron-that-will-run-a-ruby-script-every-day-at-midnight/18920378#18920378)

Answer (score 0):

I tried all combinations with PATHs, but don't work. **Probably** they are needed.

In my case, with Centos 7, **a reboot or server worked.**