# Program/Script that runs autonomously without interaction from user

Tags: php, video, automation, migration

I need to know whether it is possible to create a program/script that runs autonomously once initiated by an event (usually a mouse click) without any further interactions from the user ie. even if he closes his browser the script continues to run on the server

**Scenario**

lets say that I've got a video sharing site whose permissions,login access and all other relevant credentials are given to me .I've created a crawler in `PHP` that crawls the entire site and writes the video `src's` of all the videos on the site in a file called `log_file.txt`. Now i want to know whether it is possible to create a program that,once i initiate it , downloads the videos from the site's server onto my server using the src's in the `log_file.txt`, and this continues to work even if i shut down my computer ie. runs on the server continuously until all the videos have downloaded or otherwise

**NOTE** : this question is not intended to perform piracy of any sorts. Its just that i have a site that has got some basic video hosting and i want to perform server to server video migration without having to download it on my pc and then reuploading it to new server

Comment: The crontab is a list of commands that you want to run on a regular schedule, and also the name of the command used to manage that list. crontab stands for "cron table," because it uses the job scheduler cron to execute tasks;

Comment: @VipinSharma Elaboration please?

Comment: Please check link , it might be helpful >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358382/execute-php-script-in-cron-job

Comment: @VipinSharma it says it needs a linux server and i've got a windows server

Comment: for windows-7 Open Control Panel
Go to Administrative tools
Select Schedule Task
General Tab, Give a name to your scheduled task. e.g. Test Cron Job
Select Trigger Tab, Click "New", Select timings for executions of Cron Job
Select Actions Tab, Click "New", Select Program to execute, in our case we want to run Cron Job. So we will require to run browser. So select Firefox, Chrome, IE etc.
Suppose Cron URL is http://example.com/cronjob.php Action should be like "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplorer.exe" "http://example.com/cronjob.php"

Comment: @VipinSharma will i have to do this configuration on my laptop?