# Scheduled Email Notification using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to add a scheduled email notification system in my project.  I developed a php based registration system where the client and Realtor create a account.  In the registration process the client and Realtor will enter their zipcodes.

Is there a way to create a php script that will automatically scan through the database to check and see if the client and Realtor zipcodes match, that will do this on a scheduled task and that will email the Realtor when a client zipcode matches the Realtor zipcode.  I'm still a php newbie so please professional suggestions will help.

Comment: What exactly have you heard about cron jobs?  I think it may be time for you to read up on cron.

Comment: cron is a Linux utility which schedules a command or script on your server to run automatically at a specified time and date. A cron job is the scheduled task itself. Cron jobs can be very useful to automate repetitive tasks. - Host Gator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question has the answer . You write the code to generate the output and send mail in php. Now calling it on decided time period should be managed by cron, Its just a php page call on decided time which can be done by adding 1 line in crontab. Read following - http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/php-cron-job/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22358929/6429270