# How to run a php script each second on a cron job

Tags: javascript, children

Is it possible to run a php file/script as a child script, which runs each second while a cronjob was started?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute PHP script in cron job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358382/execute-php-script-in-cron-job)

Comment: I have tried that, unfortunately the entire duplicates start to work as the time intervel of the main php