# Php - Set time interval to run a script

Tags: php, cron, intervals

On the code above im able to have an interval until 60 Hours if the script is loaded every minute. In other words, the script above will be loaded by a cronjob every minute.

Since the users that will use this may use hosting that do not have rights to set Cronjobs, I need to make this script only with PHP.

How can I do it to make it for longer, for exemple for once a month (672 hours)?

```
/** suppose we have 1 hour and 1 minute inteval 01:01 */

    $interval_source = "01:01";
    $time_now = strtotime( "now" ) / 60;
    $interval = substr($interval_source,0,2) * 60 + substr($interval_source,3,2);


    if( $time_now % $interval == 0){
    /** Run things after interval */
    }
```

Comment: We use either cronjobs (linux) or scheduled tasks (windows) for it. No need to keep the script running.

Comment: use the crontab.

Comment: See how to use crontab with script https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358382/execute-php-script-in-cron-job

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute PHP script in cron job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358382/execute-php-script-in-cron-job)

Comment: Thanks you all for the Reply. The problem is that I can not use Cronjobs for this because the se users that will use my script may have no previleges on the hosting for that or could use windows as Server.

Answer (score 0):

If you get a reasonable amount of daily visitors you could also let a hit activate a certain script once a month for example: (I use this method to record some info about my site daily at 23h30)