# Cron job in linux for running php file

Tags: php, cron

I have an php file to create a new text file . That has to run in every minute . I stored that file on `/var/www/html/cron.php` . Also i had done  in command prompt

```
crontab -e
```

edit the file like

```
* * * * * /var/www/html/cron.php
```

But still cron not working on localhost

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute PHP script in cron job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358382/execute-php-script-in-cron-job)

Comment: Try redirecting the output of cron to a file to see the logs. for ex [ * * * * * /var/www/html/cron.php" >/var/log/cron.log 2>&1  ]

Comment: `sudo service cron reload` is your best friend here.

Comment: Also, if your script has no php-shebang (the first line of the code is #!/usr/bin/php) and it isn't executable, then you need to change that line to `* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/cron.php`

Answer (score 3):

you need to specify in the cron the command to execute, i.e

```
[cron time] [command to execute]
```

`/var/www/html/cron.php` is not a command just a file, you need to use something like

```
* * * * * php /var/www/html/cron.php
```

*better to use full path of php bin instead of `php`

Comment: It's probably better to use the absolute path of `php` (eg. `/usr/bin/php`) as `cron` can sometimes be unaware of the command.

Comment: Completely agree!

Answer (score 1):

The command you put in crontab should be something like:

```
*/10 * * * *   /usr/bin/php  /var/www/html/cron.php
```

Where `/usr/bin/php` is an example path to your `php` binary.

You can find out your `php binary` with:

```
whereis php
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
*/1 * * * * cd /var/www/html;./cron.php
```