# Lot of cURL requests stop the website execution

Tags: php, mysql, curl

I have a page that sent a cURL request for website to check their HTTP Status. (I have something like **6000** URLs to check)

Its work fine, but after 300-400 requests its stop the page with `HTTP ERROR 500`.

I try to do `sleep` function for `30 seconds` every 100 cURL requests, its not help. I also increate the `max_execution_time` to `10000`

Comment: Try limiting the number of requests per minute. Check https://dzone.com/articles/basic-api-rate-limiting

Comment: @PraveenE I dont understand this code, I using PHP

Comment: _its stop the page_ How? Is there an error?

Comment: @RiggsFolly its return me `HTTP ERROR 500` - this page wont work.

Comment: Anything useful in the error logs?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Where I can find the error logs? the page its chrome error not my server error

Answer (score -1):

Try using crontab. 
For example, you have a PHP script with cURL request, set up cron that will execute that script exery minute (* * * * * *)

Comment: How its different from sleep function?

Comment: Cron works in background mode, just try it - https://stackoverflow.com/a/30429555/10944735