# How could I run a command to execute a .php file?

Tags: php, ubuntu, cron

I'd like to create a cronjob to execute a .php file on Ubuntu but it currently does not worked.
The .php file is placed at /var/www/createfile.php to create a text file.
I've tried to executed some commands on ssh. as follow

```
    'php /usr/bin/php /var/www/createfile.php' after that,
    '/user/bin/php /var/www/createfile.php' after that,
    'php /var/www/createfile.php'
```

(those are executed one after I found that the previous command doesn't worked)

The results from those commands are the same, there is no '.txt' file as expected.
However, when I run 'php createfile.php' when I was at the directory storing the 'createfile.php', I got a '.txt' file as intending.

I'm not quite sure what did I do wrong?

thanks in advance.

// below this is what I would update, the above statement might confusing some of you. I'm sorry for that.

this is the code in '.php' targeted to execute

```
 > <?php
 $myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w");
 $txt = "Mickey Mouse\n";
 fwrite($myfile, $txt);
 fclose($myfile);
 ?>
```

Obviously, it's just simply create a file with a line of phrase.
here is the ways I'd tried but doesn't work

1. create cronjob like 'minute * * * * php /var/www/createfile.php' << this did work.
   So, I tried the commands like what I described at root directory with root permission.

However, the file was created by other user (let's say by Alice)
I have no idea if Alice vs. root permission is a certain point of concern?

HOWEVER: there currently is one way which work.
I've to run the command like 'php createfile.php' when I locating at '/var/www' (it is the path the 'createfile.php' locates) << this is the way which currently work.

Comment: With out seeing the code it's hard to say.

Comment: Your user doesn't have permission to write a file in the directory you are in.  You need to do something in the php file like `./file.txt` or `__DIR__.'file.txt` or something.  If you turn on error reporting it will tell you the issue.

Comment: Your second example will work.  But it's "usr", not "user".  :)

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358382/execute-php-script-in-cron-job

Comment: Cron may be running as a different user, in a different directory, or with other permissions.

Comment: Thank you guys, especially FoulFoot. You're right. In the question, it was mistyping, I did usr while trying at ssh. it's not worked either.

Answer (score 0):

Your issues is most likely that you're using a relative path in your script, maybe something like this:

```
<?php

file_put_contents('my/dir/file.txt', $variable)
?>
```

That will create the `file.txt` file relative to where the script is being run. If it's run by cron as your user, it would most likely put the file in `/home/username/my/dir/file.txt`.

Use the absolute path to where you want to `file.txt` to be created:

```
<?php

file_put_contents('/var/www/my/dir/file.txt', $variable)
?>
```