# Auto add new data with default value for each day every 12 PM using MySQL and Codeigniter 4

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

I am trying to create function to automatically adding rows every 12 PM each day for attendance record table, total data based on total employees, for example I have 5 employees, so I need function to adding 5 new rows with default value that I have set before.

here is my table:

[image]

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: [Using the Event Scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/event-scheduler.html)

Comment: As Akina has suggested , using the event scheduler can carry out periodic jobs. If you can provide the actual `show create table xxxx` code instead of an image, people here may elaborate with an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write php script for this work.

and scheduler it into Cron job.

You can following: [Execute PHP script in cron job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358382/execute-php-script-in-cron-job)

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.