# How I can send message at at a specific time in Telegram bots using PHP?

Tags: php, time, telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I want to program a telegram bot (using PHP) that sends messages at a specific time. So if I did this :

```
$time = date('h:i a');

if($time == "12:00 pm"){
then send a message or audio or whatever is going to do }
```

The question is will the file on my host will test the if sentence every single sec? Isn't that will create pressure on the hosting & on the bot? Are there any other alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to run the script every second; just set a cron job to run your script every minute. Look at this answer for more information:

[Execute PHP script in cron job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358382/execute-php-script-in-cron-job)

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
$time = date('h:i a');
while(true){
    if($time != "00:00 am"){
        sleep(59);
    }else{
        ## CODE TO BE EXECUTED
        break;
    }
}
```

[Sleep](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) is a function used to stop the code for **int** seconds