# how to run nodejs program every midnight?

Tags: node.js, cron

I want my node.js program to automatically execute at midnight or some particular time, every day.

I have some idea about  cron, but can anyone specify me how to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984134/cron-that-will-run-a-ruby-script-every-day-at-midnight

Comment: This is very basic crontab usage. `man 1 crontab` will tell you how to use the `crontab` command, and `man 5 crontab` will explain the syntax and semantics of a crontab.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, you can simply run `crontab -e`which will open a cron file in your default editor.

Then to have your node program running every day at midnight you'd have to enter :

```
00 00 * * * node /path/yournodeapp.js
```

And save it.

I suggest you read a bit about cron jobs, they are quite powerful but very easy to use.

[This](http://www.nncron.ru/help/EN/working/cron-format.htm) is my usual cheatsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the [cron module on NPM](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron).  It allows you to execute arbitrary node.js code at predefined intervals or times of day.