# How to run code on a certain user every 2 days?

Tags: php, mysql

is there away to execute a code 2 days at a certain time?

For example let's say John logins in and wants his password changed every two days for security purposes, how can i execute my change password code every two days from the exact time that it was requested?

thanks

Comment: it's called a cron job.

Comment: possible duplicate of [cron that will run a ruby script every day at midnight](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984134/cron-that-will-run-a-ruby-script-every-day-at-midnight)

Comment: you might have left out a question mark ;-) But yeah, I'd say so :-)

Answer (score 0):

Cron jobs stand for Chronological Jobs.  Cron jobs can act like a repeating stop watch sett running code, in this case every 48 hours.  My memory aide is to spell them "Chron" jobs.

The basics are simple.  Write the PHP code that should run every 2 days. Then sign into the server (which is specific to you) and look for cron jobs.  Schedule a cron job to run every two days and specify the path to the code that the cron job should run.

Another possible way is to create a small bit of code that executes every time someone visits your website or a particular page of your website.  If you have enough traffic and the code runs X number of times a day, then that same code will run, more or less, every two days.  Keep track of the days that the script executed either in a database or in a text file. Check the date the script last ran.  If that is greater then two days, run the php code that needs to run every two days and save the new date that it ran to the db or text file.  This is less precise but it can be just as effective under the right circumstances.

In John's case, store the last day he signed in the database, check it, if it is greater than two days have it include the php code that requires him to change his password.

"Cron Jobs" are just one way of talking about it.  Your system may call it something different.

Comment: Its called cron, not chron.

Comment: @geeves Thing is i need to do this for all users that have purchased a certain package, so it can't be manual

Comment: @AlBundy right.  Your correct.  It is cron.  It helps me to think of it as chron though.  Just an old quirk:

http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29986/origin-of-the-word-cron